# Difference between "Ubuntu OpenStack: The Canonical Distribution" and plain old Ubuntu Openstack distribution

Tags: juju, maas, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I was trying to deploy Openstack on Ubuntu. I found following two different links:

- [UbuntuCloudInfrastructure | Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure)
- [Build OpenStack with conjure-up | Download | Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack)

I am not sure that what is the difference between above two ways of installing Ubuntu Openstack? Both are setting up MAAS, both are setting up Juju. both will deploy charms. So, my question here is

How is "ubuntu OpenStack: The Canonical Distribution" different than the Ubuntu openstack distribution?  What makes "The Canonical Distribution" special? What extra advantages "The Canonical Distribution" has over ubuntu Openstack Distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu OpenStack is based on the same packages Ubuntu OpenStack is, but is deployed as a standard reference architecture using Landscape automation (we call this the OpenStack Autopilot), and is a brand associated with using Ubuntu technologies within Canonical's best practices.

One thing is building an Ubuntu OpenStack using the bits, when it is done according to our reference architecture (full disclaimer: I work for Canonical), we call it Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu OpenStack (pun somewhat intended) to indicate our best practices, automation, and way of doing and maintaining things has been put in place.

Comment: Is canonical distribution of Openstack free for more than 10 machines?

Comment: The Canonical Distribution, by definition, involves Canonical in some way - which usually means you are paying for service.

The OpenStack Autopilot, which is used by the Canonical Distribution, includes 10 free VMs and 10 free physical for Landscape (for clarity, let me point out here that the Autopilot is part of Landscape)

Comment: So we will be charged for the Landscape only?

Comment: That question is open-ended. You will be charged for whatever services you decide to purchase... you don't have to purchase anything unless you want to.